# Именование groupId и artifactId

Tags: maven

Мой пример:

**groupId:**

com.namecompany.nameproject

**artifactId:**

nameproject

Вопрос: правильно ли такое именование? Если проект включает модули - то **artifactId** они должны иметь, **artifactId:nameprojectNamemodule** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**groupId** и **artifactId** могут быть любыми строками (без пробелов). Если вы не планирует распространять свои артефакты используя публичные сервера, то вы вольны поставить туда абсолютно любые значения.

Если вы планирует распространять свои артефакты, то:

- для **groupId** рекомендуется использовать такую же схему как и для пакетов в вашем артефакте. Обычно в качестве **groupId** выбирают имя корневого пакета. Но **groupId** может отличаться от имен пакетов.
- для **artifactId** рекомендуется использовать строку которая описывает содержимое артефакта. Если ваш проект содержит много артефактов, то у них может совпадать **groupId**.
- для **version** рекомендуется использовать цифры разделенные точками (1.0, 2.3). Если это не релиз версия, то в конце добавляют `-SNAPSHOT` (1.0-SNAPSHOT).

Подобные соглашения нужны для того, что бы maven (и другие системы сборки или системы разрешения зависимостей) мог найти ваши артефакты и добавить их в проект.

Если ваш проект содержит несколько отдельных модулей, то обычно они имеют одинаковый **groupId** (но это не обязательно) и разные **artifactId**.

Comment: Мой проект имеет несколько модулей. Т.е. я правильно написал в примере?

Comment: нет. вы не правильно написали. **artifactId** это грубо говоря имя файла. может имя содержать **:**?

Comment: Я написал **artifactId** : nameprojectNamemodule,т.е. nameprojectNamemodule вот **artifactId**

Comment: да. так можно. хотя я не вижу смысла добавлять имя проекта в имя артефакта.